# command to clean apache-karaf cache

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

Is there any command to clean the karaf container?
ie) I am trying to create a bundle and installing the bundle multiple times in apache-karaf-2.3.10. After certain number of tries karaf is not performing as expected. Sometimes names are not appearing instead absolute path of the bundle appears. So i am expecting a karaf shell command to clean the data cache folder so that karaf goes back to original state(kind of factory reset).

Answer (score 5):

The cache holds the state of the OSGi framework. It can not be cleaned while karaf is running.

You can use `shutdown -cc` to restart and clean the cache.

Comment: So I'd say it is not a cache

Answer (score 5):

When you start karaf from the command line, use the `clean` command.

i.e.

```
~/home/karaf/bin: ./karaf clean
```

See https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/start-stop.html#Cleanstart for more detail.

There is no way to do it from within Karaf - it wouldn't make sense for the reason Christian Schneider describes above.